Formula for jointly correlated variables
I've always seen the following expression for normal correlated variables which is considered quite basic:
\begin{equation}
A=\rho Z+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\epsilon
\end{equation}
I understand that it follows several statistical properties, but my question is simple: Where is this coming from?
I've always seen it as given and never have found the deduction of that formula. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

This formula is the simplest method to construct from two independent standard normals $Z$ and $\epsilon$ a standard normal $A$ that has desired correlation $\rho$ with $Z,.$ That's all. Beware of thinking that any two correlated standard normals $A,Z$ could be written in that form. This is false.

I don't know if it helps but here it is proven: link
